# QtQuick, QML - How do I copy one Item's child to another?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-quick

Using QML, I'd like to copy one Item's child to another. Here's what I tried:

```
Item
{
    id: itemOne;
    Component.onCompleted: {  children.push(itemTwo.children[0]);  }
}

Row
{   // has many children

    id: itemTwo;
    Image {}
    Image {}
    Image {}
}
```

I get an error like: TypeError: Result of expression 'children.push' [undefined] is not a function. So how do I copy children over then? I'd appreciate any advice

-tricky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An item cannot be copied because it cannot have multiple parents.

Instead of copying, try creating the new child dynamically, as described in [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html), and pass 'itemTwo' as the id for the parent of the new child.